# Deploy PHP Slim project to Hostgator using subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim, shared-hosting

I have a very simple Slim app that works fine on my Ubuntu machine but I get an error 500 when I deploy it to a Hostgator shared account using a subdomain.

I suspect the problem lies in my .htaccess file.

The structure of my files is:

```
project/
├──api/
│  ├── .htaccess
│  ├── services.php
├──src/
   ├──vendor/
```

My Slim app (services.php):

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
require_once '../src/vendor/autoload.php';

$c = new \Slim\Container();

$c['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {
        return $c['response']
            ->withStatus(404)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write('Invalid endpoint');
    };
};

$app = new \Slim\App($c);   
$app->post('/myEndpoint', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    if($request->getHeader("key") != null && $request->getHeader("key")[0] == "123456789="){
        $reqdata = $request->getParsedBody();
        $data = $reqdata['data'];
        return json_encode('{"data":'.$data.',"response":"OK","errorcode":"0"}');       
    } else {
        return '{"data":"","response":"Access denied","errorcode":"9999"}';
    }
});

$app->run();
```

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule . services.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# Use PHP71 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php71/lib
</IfModule>
```

I created a subdomain (api.mydomain.com) with project/api/ as document root.

When I make a POST request in my local installation to

```
127.0.0.1/api/services.php/myEndpoint
```

works as expected and returns the data. However, when I make the same request to my Hostgator subdomain:

```
api.mydomain.com/services.php/myEndpoint
```

I get the error 500.

Note that if I add a simple test.php file to my api/ directory that only prints something, e.g.

```
<?php
  echo "OK"
?>
```

and I go to api.mydomain.com/test.php, it works fine and prints the string.

What do I need to change or add in my .htaccess for my slim app to work?

Comment: @odan I tried it but it's not even working locally on my machine. I tried it on my server. I create a subdomain just for that: helloworld.mydomain.com but I get a 404 error

Comment: @odan correction: I was fetching the wrong URL. With the correct URL I still get a 500 error

Comment: @odan and locally, when I go to http://127.0.0.1/helloworld/ I just get a list of files and folders

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing two things:

1. I moved my project folder to public_html, created again the subdomain and pointed it to the project directory.
2. I updated my .htaccess file IfModule mod_rewrite.c section. It now looks like this:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ services.php [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

The difference with the previous one is I added this line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

And this one:

```
RewriteRule . services.php [QSA,L]
```

updated to this:

```
RewriteRule ^ services.php [QSA,L]
```

I got the .htaccess fixes here:

https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/deploy-slim-project-to-hostgator-using-subdomain/3187/7